# Lock window to a specific display (winapi)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to prevent a window from being moved between monitors by checking for the message WM_MOVE and using the SetWindowPos function to keep the window within the bounds of the display.  When I try to do this, the window briefly flashes where the mouse is and snaps to a small area on the bottom of the screen.  I'm not sure why this is happening, since the code is just like any other collision detection:

```
case WM_MOVE:
{
    int nX = (int)(short)LOWORD(lParam);
    int nY = (int)(short)HIWORD(lParam);

    if (nX < pDisplayDevice->getLeft()) {
        nX = pDisplayDevice->getLeft();
    } else if (nX + int(uNormalWidth) > pDisplayDevice->getRight()) {
        nX = pDisplayDevice->getRight() - int(uNormalWidth);
    }

    if (nY < pDisplayDevice->getTop()) {
        nY = pDisplayDevice->getTop();
    } else if (nY + int(uNormalHeight) > pDisplayDevice->getBottom()) {
        nY = pDisplayDevice->getBottom() - int(uNormalHeight);
    }

    SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0, nX, nY, uNormalWidth, uNormalHeight, 0);
}
break;
```

pDisplayDevice is basically a pointer to a Rect that contains the coordinates of the display, and uNormalWidth/uNormalHeight are the width and height of the window in windowed mode.

Comment: You might have better results if you intercept WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING.

Comment: What are the values of `uNormalWidth` and `uNormalHeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WM_MOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631.aspx)

> lParam The x and y coordinates of the upper-left corner of the **client**
>   area of the window. The low-order word contains the x-coordinate while
>   the high-order word contains the y coordinate.

Each time you enter WM_MOUSE, you Move your windows +8 pixels to the right and +30 pixels to the bottom (no menu in my code). That's the Width of the left sizing border and the height of the top sizing border + Title bar.

That move triggers a recursive chain of WM_MOVE processing, eventually ending up with some coords.

What you could do:

**1.** Follow Jonathan' advice. WM_MOVE is not the message you are looking for, it's [WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653.aspx).

**2.** Use the NON-client coordinates:

```
int nX = (int)(short)LOWORD(lParam);
int nY = (int)(short)HIWORD(lParam);

RECT rect;
GetWindowRect( hWnd, &rect );
nX = rect.left;
nY = rect.top;

if (nX < pDisplayDevice->getLeft()) {

[...]
```

Comment: This works, but the window is still flashing when I move it out of bounds.  Is this because the windowing server has latency and what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: If you rely on WM_MOUSE, you are late: the window has already a new position. WHY don't you just follow advices to use WM_WINDOWPOSCHHANGING?

Comment: I am - it's flashing, but not snapping anymore.

Comment: OK. Don't use SetWindowPos in WM_WINDOWPOSCHHANGING. Adjust the WINDOWPOS struct passed in lParam before returning.

Comment: Like this? `WINDOWPOS* pWindowPos = (WINDOWPOS*)(lParam);
     pWindowPos->x = nX;
     pWindowPos->y = nY;`  The window is frozen in place if I do this (I'm returning 0).

Comment: I should also mention the window style is WS_OVERLAPPED.

Comment: Woops - fixed it.  GetWindowRect gets the previous position of the window, if I just use the WINDOWPOS struct I get the new position.  No more flashing!